# Covariance of two additions of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, distribution-theory, covariance

I have a set of independent random variables $A_{1}, A_{2}, ... , A_{n}, n \geq 7$ with

$ \forall i \in[1, n], \ \mathbb{E}(A_{i}) = 0 \ \& \text{ Var}(A_{i}) = 1$

I have two other random variables, B and C where

$B = 5A_{p} + 7A_{p-3}, p\geq 4 $ and $C = 13A_{p+7m} - 6A_{p-3+4m}, m \geq 0$

I am attempting to determine Cov(B, C)

Everything I have attempted so far makes me believe the answer is $0$ but I feel this can't be right.

Comment: Where are the "sums" mentioned in the title?

Comment: @aschepler sorry, put wrong thing in title will fix

Comment: So only four of the $n$ variables $A_i$ are used to define $B$ and $C$?

Comment: Yes that is the case, but p and m are unknowns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for integers $p, m$ satisfying the given criteria, the set $\{p, p-3, p+7m, p-3+4m\}$ are all distinct unless $m = 0$, since $p = p-3$ is impossible; $p = p+7m$ or $p-3 = p-3 + 4m$ implies $m = 0$; $p = p-3 + 4m$ or $p-3 = p+7m$ implies $m$ is not an integer; and $p+7m = p-3 + 4m$ implies $m$ is negative.

If $m = 0$, then
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}[B,C]
&= \operatorname{Cov}[5A_p + 7A_{p-3}, 13A_p - 6A_{p-3}] \\
&= 5(13) \operatorname{Cov}[A_p, A_p] - 5(6)\operatorname{Cov}[A_p, A_{p-3}] + 7(13)\operatorname{Cov}[A_{p-3}, A_p] - 7(6)\operatorname{Cov}[A_{p-3},A_{p-3}] \\
&= 65 \operatorname{Var}[A_p] - 42\operatorname{Var}[A_{p-3}] \\
&= 23.
\end{align}$$

If $m \ne 0$, then it is obvious that $\operatorname{Cov}[B,C] = 0$.